# Determine total size of SVN directory/trunk

Tags: svn, download, size

Is there a way to count/calculate the total size of a svn directory if you were to checkout a revision?

I have limited internet downloads so I need to know how big something is before I go and download it.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the below, you can determine the size of individual files.

```
svn list --verbose --recursive http://svn/repo/path
```

Maybe you can look around this command to find a way?

Comment: Seems to work fine, but takes an awful while and no idea how much traffic that gobbles up already. In PowerShell it's as easy as: `([xml](svn list --xml --recursive https://svn/repo/path)).lists.list.entry | measure -sum size`

Comment: No. Externals are a whole other ballgame.

Answer (score 38):

This is my modification to the answer. It reports how many files are below a certain directory in svn and the total size.

```
svn list -vR svn://svn/repo/subdir|awk '{if ($3 !="") sum+=$3; i++} END {print "\ntotal size= " sum/(1024*1024)" MB" "\nnumber of files= " i/1000 " K"}'
```

Comment: no, this is still running for more than 1 hour for checking the size of an <15GB repo-dir. Still waiting............. :(

Comment: Nice command. Tested it before checking out the directory and the size of the final local directory minus the size of the .svn directory matched the one that your command gave

Answer (score 7):

I've tested the PowerShell solution and it just needs a small correction:

```
([xml](svn list --xml --recursive https://svn/repo/path)).lists.list.entry | measure-object -sum size
```

It some time to get the xml, but works very well.

Answer (score 3):

I needed the sizes on base project folder level.
Here is my solution using powershell to generate the xml and a C# app to extract the summarized sizes for each base project folder.

```
PS C:\> svn list --xml --recursive https://svn.xy.com:4443/svn/Production/ >svn_extract.xml
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace SvnProjectSizeFromXml
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //create svn repository xml file via powershell first:
                //PS C:\> svn list --xml --recursive https://svn.xy.com:4443/svn/Production/ >svn_extract
            //read file via streamreader, extract rootfolders and summarized size - export to csv

            string fileName = @"C:\svn_extract.xml";

            Dictionary<string, Int64> list = new Dictionary<string, Int64>();
            string currentProject="";
            Int64 currentSize=0;

            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = String.Empty;
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (s.Contains("<name>") || s.Contains("</lists>"))
                    {
                        if (s.Contains("</lists>"))
                        {
                            //end of file
                            list.Add(currentProject, currentSize);
                            break;
                        }
                        XmlDocument docNew = new XmlDocument();
                        docNew.LoadXml(s);
                        if (!docNew.InnerText.Contains("/") && !docNew.InnerText.Contains("."))
                        {
                            if (currentProject != docNew.InnerText && currentProject!= "")
                            {
                                //new project, store last one to list 
                                list.Add(currentProject, currentSize);
                                Console.WriteLine(list.Count.ToString());
                            }
                            //new project, init
                            currentProject = docNew.InnerText;
                            currentSize = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    if (s.Contains("<size>"))
                    {
                        XmlDocument docNew = new XmlDocument();
                        docNew.LoadXml(s);

                        currentSize += Int64.Parse(docNew.InnerText);
                    }
                }

                String csv = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,list.Select(d => $"{d.Key};{d.Value};"));

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\output.csv", csv);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output as CSV:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adopting from the above solutions, the following might be helpful

```
#------------------------- Show Repositories, Revisions and Individual Sizes -------------------- SuN ---  2011-11-14 -- {

CSVN_DIR=/opt/csvn

cd ${CSVN_DIR}

REPO_PREFIX="${CSVN_DIR}/data/repositories"
REPO_SUFFIX="db/current"


for i in `ls ${REPO_PREFIX}/*/${REPO_SUFFIX} `
do
  if [ -f $i ]
  then
    FILENAME=`ls -l $i`
    REV_NO=`cat $i`
    REPONAME=`echo  $i | awk '{ srch="'${REPO_PREFIX}'/";  idx = index($0,srch); xstr=substr($0,idx + length(srch)); idx = index(xstr, "/'${REPO_SUFFIX}'"); print substr(xstr,1,idx-1)}'`

    #REPONAME=sn_library

    ${CSVN_DIR}/bin/svn list --verbose --recursive https://vctl.ds.xxxxxx.in:9501/svn/${REPONAME} | awk 'BEGIN {repo="'${REPONAME}'"; rev="'${REV_NO}'";} {print "Repository: " repo " Revision: " rev $0 } '
  fi
done
#------------------------- Show Repositories, Revisions and Individual Sizes -------------------- SuN ---  2011-11-14 -- }
```

or

```
#------------------------- Show Versions of Repositories and Total Size -------------------- SuN ---  2011-11-14 -- {

CSVN_DIR=/opt/csvn
cd ${CSVN_DIR}

REPO_PREFIX="${CSVN_DIR}/data/repositories"
REPO_SUFFIX="db/current"


for i in `ls ${REPO_PREFIX}/*/${REPO_SUFFIX} `
do
  if [ -f $i ]
  then
    FILENAME=`ls -l $i`
    REV_NO=`awk '{print $1; exit}' $i`
    REPONAME=`echo  $i | awk '{ srch="'${REPO_PREFIX}'/";  idx = index($0,srch); xstr=substr($0,idx + length(srch)); idx = index(xstr, "/'${REPO_SUFFIX}'"); print substr(xstr,1,idx-1)}'`

    #REPONAME=sn_library
    COL_PREFIX="Repository:\t${REPONAME}\tRevision No:\t${REV_NO}\t${FILENAME}"

    COL_PREFIX=`echo "${COL_PREFIX}" | awk '{xstr = $0; gsub(" ","_",xstr); gsub(":","_",xstr); print xstr;}'`


    ${CSVN_DIR}/bin/svn list -vR https://vctl.ds.xxxxxx.in:9501/svn/${REPONAME} | awk 'BEGIN{xstr="'${COL_PREFIX}'"} {if ($3 !="") sum+=$3; i++} END {print xstr "\tTotal size= \t" sum/1024/1024 "\tMB" "\t spread across \t" i "\tfiles/folders "}'

  fi
done

#------------------------- Show Versions of Repositories and Total Size -------------------- SuN ---  2011-11-14 -- }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XML mode of the Subversion list command and sum over the file size.

On Linux/UNIX:

```
$ svn list --xml --recursive http://svn.example.org/module/trunk | awk -F'[><]' \
      '/^ *<size>/ {s+=$3} END {printf("%.1f GiB\n", s/1024/1024/1024)}'
```

Note that the disk usage of an actual svn checkout is basically twice as much as computed above because in the checkout you have the files in the working directory and in the revision cache under the `.svn` special directory/directories.

Alternatively, if you aren't overly concerned about RAM usage you use an XPath expression to compute the sum, e.g.:

```
$ printf '%.1f GiB\n' $(svn list --xml --recursive \
     http://svn.example.org/module/trunk | xmlstarlet sel -t -v \
       'sum(/lists/list/entry/size) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024')
```

Or:

```
$ printf '%.1f GiB\n' $(svn list --xml --recursive \
     http://svn.example.org/module/trunk | xmllint --xpath \
       'sum(/lists/list/entry/size) div 1024 div 1024 div 1024' -)
```

Using such an XPath processor on a repository with many files may yield high memory usage because tools like xmllint (that uses libxml2) often construct the complete document tree in memory before starting to sum over the elements.